# Writing Swagger documentation for requests in body without model referencing

Tags: php, swagger, symfony4, nelmioapidocbundle

How to write Swagger documentation for requests in body without model referencing?

e.g:

```
@SWG\Parameter( 
    name="date",
    in="body",
    content="application/json",
    type="object",
    {custom written JSON}
)
```

I have tried to do it in description, but that is not going to work 
because it have to be shown in `Edit Value` field.

Similar for requests, too.

I have searched google, but found no solution.
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but in not very obvious way. This works for me:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *  path="/route",
 *  tags={"tag"},
 *  @SWG\Response(
 *      response="200",
 *      description="Simple list of name and value pairs ",
 *      @SWG\Schema(
 *          type="array",
 *          @SWG\Items(
 *                  @SWG\Property(
 *                      property="id",
 *                      type="string"
 *                  ),
 *                  @SWG\Property(
 *                      property="name",
 *                      type="string"
 *                  )
 *          )
 *      )
 *  )
 * )
 */
```

Comment: That works, but how would I do it with values, something like this:  

{  
    "data": 
          {
               "type": "success",
               "id": "734234"
           }
}  

I've tried with description, but no luck.